# Where are SharePoint resources strings located

Tags: sharepoint, resources, master-pages, page-layout

I have a page layout, PeopleSearchResults.aspx programmed by someone else.
It contains the following tag for a [SharePoint refine people search results control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.refinesearchresults.aspx).

```
Title="<%$Resources:sps,RefineByTitle%>"
```

Where on earth/SharePoint do I look to find the string that code references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular file you specified, sps.resx is actually in 12\CONFIG\Resources (but there's a bunch of others in 12\Resources).

Answer (score 2):

> Where are SharePoint resources strings
>   located.

The provisioning resources are located in the **12 hive** in ..\12\Resources.

The 12 Hive is a directory most often found at: *C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12*.

So to answer your question, assuming your sharepoint install is on drive C, look in the ***C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Resources*** folder.

Answer (score 1):

="<%$Resources:sps,RefineByTitle%>"

sps (.resx) is the name of the resource file in 12\Resources (there may be several with extra bits such as .en-us.resx, fr-fr.resx etc if you have multiple languages supported) and RefineByTitle is the key of the language entry in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Also, look in the App_GlobalResources folder for your web site. (determined from IIS Manager)